# C# アセンブリ出力無しのプロジェクトをVisual Studioで作成できますか？

Tags: c#, visual-studio

タイトルの件、ズバリ可能でしょうか？

ビルドやSetupProjectの出力対象としたときに、参照するライブラリだけ出力して
自分自身のライブラリは、コードも1行も書いていない（*.csファイルがプロジェクトに無い）ので
出力しないようにしたいです。

よろしくお願いいたします。

Answer (score 2, accepted):

.csproj内部に`<Import Project="$(MSBuildBinPath)\Microsoft.CSharp.targets" />`の記述がある場合はアセンブリ出力が記述されていないとコンパイルエラーになるため、おそらく出力しない.csprojを作成することは不可能ではないかと考えています。
[MSBuildプロパティ](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ja-jp/library/bb629394.aspx)の`OutputPath`や`OutputType`を削除してもダメでした。

疑似的にアセンブリを出力しないプロジェクトは、下記で作成できますがいかがでしょうか。

1. プロジェクトのプロパティ - アプリケーション -  出力の種類を「コンソール アプリケーション」に変える

   - これで.csファイルを含まないプロジェクトがコンパイルできる
2. プロジェクトのプロパティ - ビルドイベント -  ビルド後イベントのコマンドラインにアセンブリを消すコマンドを追加する

   del $(TargetFileName)
   del $(TargetFileName).config
   del $(TargetName).pdb

Answer (score 2):

csproj ファイルのProject要素の DefaultTargets に自分で定義したターゲットを指定することで、一応そういうことも可能ではあるかと思います。
私の場合、以下のような感じでクラスライブラリプロジェクトと同列にNuGetパッケージのビルド用プロジェクトを作って、使っていたりします。

```
<Project DefaultTargets="BuildNuPkg" ・・・・・>
  ・・・・・
  <Target Name="BuildNuPkg" Condition=" '$(Configuration)' == 'Release' ">
    ・・パッケージ作成タスク・・
  </Target>
</Project>
```

Copyタスクというものがあるので、それ使って以下のような感じも可能ではあります。

```
<Project DefaultTargets="MyTask" ・・・・・>
  ・・・・・
  <Target Name="MyTask">
    <Copy SourceFiles="..\ClassLibrary1\bin\$(Configuration)\ClassLibrary1.dll" DestinationFolder="$(OutDir)" />
  </Target>
</Project>
```

ただ、この方法だと参照を増やしたらこの定義も増やさないといけないのでメンテナンス面で微妙かもしれませんけども。
ビルドタスクの自作もできるようですがそういった方法や、他のビルドタスクで有用なものがないかとかまではそこまで詳しく把握していないのでわかりませんが。
簡潔さや管理上は不要ファイルを削除するほうが良いかもしれませんね。